# React Native Sqlite enablePromise option

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

In the react-native-sqlite-storage package:

https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

There is an option to enable promises:

```
SQLite.enablePromise(true);
```

Do I have to enable this option in react native projects ? How react native works differently when I not enable it ? Does the components wait for the queries to complete (synchronously) before rendering if not enabled ?